# Naming your android app

Tags: android

I have created an app on Android and for some reason it is unnamed when seen on the phone
My manifest file is

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/bampong" android:label="BAM! Pong" android:debuggable="true">


<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".Start"><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
```

I tried adding android:name="appname",but gives an error

Comment: So, what error message are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a string resource "app_name." (The file will be res/values/string.xml.) See the Android [Hello World example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) for more information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello, Android! I am a string resource!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Hello, Android</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: You have that in your string.xml file, or in your Manifest? (You'll need it in string.xml.)

Comment: got it just did not set the value

Comment: @Raj - Sorry...just to see if I understood - did you get it to work?